# Rails before_destroy callback db changes always rolled back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, callback, rails-activerecord, activemodel

I'm trying to prevent deletion of models from the db and pretty much follow this [guide](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=2) (see **9.2.5.3 Exercise Your Paranoia with before_destroy**) from a Rails 4 book.

I have a simple model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy do
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
    false
  end
```

and in the controller:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  # @user.update!(deleted_at: Time.zone.now) # if I do it here it works
  @user.destroy # if I also comment this line...

  render :show
end
```

The callback gets called and the attribute gets set, but then the database transaction always gets rolled back. It I leave out the returning of `false` the model gets deleted because the execution of delete is not halted.

As you can see in the comments I can get it to work but what I really want to do is use a Service Object and put the logic out of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your callback returns false the transaction will always be rollbacked.

For what you want you should not call to the `destroy` method on your arel object.
Instead, make your own method like `soft_destroy` or something like that and update your attribute.

And to prevent others from calling the `destroy` method on your arel object, just add a callback raising and exception for instance.

Comment: I guessed that the *false* is the reason. Thanks for confirming. It's strange that it is suggested in a book. I will go the route you proposed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is just an object. If you really want to change the concept of destroy, change it:

```
def destroy
  condition ? alt_action : super
end
```